# How to check the rate of difference of values

Tags: ruby

I want to check if a value is enough similar to another.

For that purpose I wrote this:

```
class Numeric
  def differ_within(other, num)
    between?(other * (1 - num), other * (1 + num))
  end
end
```

This code works fine, but I want to know if there is a existing method like this in core ruby or `active_support` or something else.

And I couldn't come up with good name of the method.
Do you have any idea of a name that represent more properly the function of the method.

Comment: In your method, `other` remains unused as argument.

Comment: Typically, [test frameworks](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-8/docs/built-in-matchers/be-within-matcher) have that kind of stuff, but they are matchers, a little different from ordinary predicate methods.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no equivalent built-in method in pure Ruby. How about `def max_fractional_deviation?(other, fraction); (self-other).abs <= fraction*other; end`?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the name `within_error_tolerance?` or something like it.  In a call it would look like this:

```
x.within_error_tolerance?(y, 0.05)
```

The term 'differ' is in my opinion redundant.  Also, I was surprised that you were using a decimal fraction and not an absolute amount (i.e. 5% rather than 120) (not that it's wrong to use a fraction, it makes sense, but it wasn't clear to me), so it would be helpful for the method name to convey that it's a fraction.  Error tolerances are usually expressed as percentages, so using 'error tolerance' in the name makes sense to me.

Another issue is, would x be the expected amount or the observed amount? Assuming:

```
class Numeric
  def within_error_tolerance?(other, tolerance)
    between?(other * (1 - tolerance), other * (1 + tolerance))
  end
end
```

then switching the parameter and the message receiver would yield different results:

```
2.3.0 :071 > 100.within_error_tolerance?(150, 0.4)
 => true
2.3.0 :072 > 150.within_error_tolerance?(100, 0.4)
 => false
```

...so one would need to be careful how it is called.